# Move Physical Windows Server 2008 into a Hyper-V VM

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v

I'd like to import a real Windows Server 2008 server as a Hyper-V Virtual Server on another Windows Server 2008 instance.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

I'm looking at the System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2008 but it doesn't seem to import Windows Server 2008 - nor is it free.

Is there some other workaround (i.e. import the image into VMWare first, then convert to Hyper-V)?

Please help.

Regards,
Randall

Comment: Goto to http://serverfault.com and ask to be part of the private beta.  That's really a more appropriate forum for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while testing disaster recovery, iwas pleasantly surprised 
(and impressed) that the builtin windows server backup
restored to hyper-v without a hitch.
this was on production hardware, with hw raid 5 and such -
so i expect it would work with slightly less exotic stuff as well.

Comment: I'm going to try this first as I've had great difficulty in getting VMWare Server to run on Windows Server 2008.  I never even thought about using the built-in backup.

Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll let everyone know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  This worked very nicely, but it was VERY slow.  However, I didn't experience any problems.  Thanks again.

Comment: Odd that it was slow - my tests were amazingly quick. As in about 5 mins to take the backup (to a networked drive), and maybe 15 mins to restore (to a dynamically sized drive). The server was relatively barebones, though.

Answer (score 0):

I know from personal experience that using VMware's converter works to take an image of the system. You can then use Hyper V to import the VMware image you created.

When I was testing the the beta version of Hyper-V this was the only reliable method I found to import a physical system into a Hyper-V environment.

It's seems crazy to doubled convert something, but it worked!